# How to understand this example of finding a particular solution with the Method of Undetermined Coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This is likely a fairly basic question but for some reason I was having trouble following this particular example from a differential equations book I'm reading for review.

The book in question is *Differential Equations for Dummies* by Steven Holzner. The example is from chapter 6, which is on second order linear nonhomogeneous differential equations (p. 127 in my edition for those that are curious). The example is of finding a particular solution with the method of undetermined coefficient given a function $g(x)$ that's a combination of sines and cosines.

The equation to solve is $$y'' - y' - 2y = sin 2x$$

The book then tells us that the particular solution will be of the form $$Asin2x + B cos 2x$$

So far, so good. To verify the solution, they substitute the solution into the equation to get $$(-6A+2B)sin 2x + (-6B - 2A)cos 2x = sin 2x$$

I'm lost at this point as to where they got $-6A+2B$ and $-6B-2A$; unless I'm missing something really obvious, that doesn't seem to be the derivative of any of the terms. Can someone explain to me where they came up with $-6A+2B$ and $-6B-2A$?

I think I follow the rest of the example, but for completeness, they then equate the coefficients of $sin 2x$ and $cos 2x$ to get the following equations:
$$-6A+2B=1$$
$$-6B-2A=0$$

Multiplying $-6B - 2A = 0$ by $-3$ and adding the result of $6A+2B=1$ gives us $20B=1$, so $B = \frac{1}{20}$. Substituting that number into $-6B-2A=0$ gives us the equation: $$\frac{-6}{20} - 2A=0$$
so obviously $A = -\frac{3}{20}$

Again, I follow all of that last bit, I just don't understand where $-6A+2B$ and $-6B-2A$ came from.

Comment: Every derivative you take brings a factor of 2 due to the chain rule, so two derivatives yield a 4 as a coefficient, add that to the undifferentiated term to obtain a 6. The part with 2 as a coefficient comes from the first derivative term

Comment: @Triatticus Thanks, that makes sense - if that's the case, though, wouldn't there have to be a $4B$ too from the first derivative (or am I missing something dumb)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll just do the $\sin{2x}$ term to show what happens: if $y=\sin{2x}$ one finds
$$ y' = 2\cos{2x} \\
y'' = -4\sin{2x}, $$
so
$$ y''-y'-2y = -4\sin{2x}-2\cos{2x}-2\sin{2x} = -6\sin{2x}-2\cos{2x}. $$
Hence if you have $A$ times this term, it contributes $-6A\sin{2x}-2A\cos{2x}$. Do the same to the $\cos{2x}$ term and you'll get the $B$ terms.